# can i install and use openbsd without sets?

Tags: installation, system, openbsd

I am trying to install openbsd on a virtual machine thanks to vmware workstation.

I follow a tutorial, and at some point I have to download a set of files via http/ftp/cd i choose ftp and use a valid ftp server that does not require authentication, but the installer cannot find the files needed :

```
 bsd            etc53.tgz      xbase53.tgz    xserv53.tgz
 bsd.rd         comp53.tgz    xetc53.tgz
 bsd.mp         man53.tgz      xshare53.tgz
 base53.tgz     game53.tgz     xfont53.tgz
```

[Here](http://ftp.ch.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/snapshots/i386/) is the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your link shows that you are trying to get the snapshot sets.
You see OpenBSD releases are organised as follows in the mirrors:

> OpenBSD/X.Y/ARCH/xxxx.tgz

(X.Y) is the version of OpenBSD you are trying to install
ARCH is your architecture (i386,macppc,...)
and xxxx.tgz are the set names.
Packages reside in paths like OpenBSD/X.Y/packages/ARCH/wwww.tgz
But it also offers a snapshot directory that are OpenBSD-current base sets and pkgs
those reside under

> OpenBSD/snapshots/ARCH/  for sets 
>    OpenBSD/snapshots/packages/ARCH for packages

So you should check that:
 (A) if you want to use -current you have the correct installation
disk from a -current release (the bsd.rd should be built around the same time with the sets that reside in the servers***)  or
(B) You want to install a stable OpenBSD release so better get cd53.iso and it will look 
on the correct mirror path.
I would suggest that you install a stable release and then upgrade to -current if you need to...

cheers

***Edit: The reason this happens is : on each -current build of the sets (lets say every 10 days or so) each one of them has an md5sum that is known to each new bsd.rd . So if you have an old bsd.rd from -current that has been pulled from the servers , it will not be able to match the current -current md5sums of the sets. So if this happens while trying to update the system via a bsd.rd you should just fetch a newer one and restart the upgrade process)